# Why doesn't Akka HTTP match my JSON body?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am trying to follow the example at https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/json-support.html

My code looks like

```
final case class LeaderboardPostRequest(name: String, kind: String)
final case class LeaderboardPostResponse(name: Option[String], id: String)

trait JsonSupport extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val requestFormat = jsonFormat2(LeaderboardPostRequest)
  implicit val responseFormat = jsonFormat2(LeaderboardPostResponse)
}

class LeaderboardEndpoint extends Directives with JsonSupport {
. . .
  def leaderboardPost(name: Option[String]): Route =
    post {
      logRequest("leaderboard", Logging.InfoLevel) {
        entity(as[LeaderboardPostRequest]) { leaderboard =>
          try {
            complete(leaderboardCreate(Some(leaderboard.name), Some(leaderboard.kind)))
          } catch {
            case cause: LeaderboardException => complete(cause.getHttpResponse)
            case cause: Throwable =>
            complete(HttpResponse(InternalServerError, entity = s"Exception thrown from LeaderboardPost: ${cause.getMessage}"))
          }
        } ~
        complete(HttpResponse(BadRequest, entity = "****body missing****"))
    }
  }
. . .
}
```

The log looks like

```
HttpRequest(HttpMethod(POST),http://localhost:8080/leaderboard?name=foo,List(User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 10.0; en-CA) WindowsPowerShell/5.1.17763.134, Host: localhost:8080, Timeout-Access: <function1>),HttpEntity.Strict(application/json,{name="foo",kind="ConcurrentLeaderboard"}),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1))
```

but the result is always

```
 ****body missing****
```

I suspect it's something simple, but I am blocked and cannot figure out what extra magic is required. Help/suggestions/hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i think there might be several (maybe intersecting) problems:

1. from what i see in the log message, it is that the `path` of the route is not configured, pls refer to [path directive docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/path-directives/index.html#overview-of-path-directives).
2. maybe you misused `logRequest` methods. the parameter value `"leaderbord"` is just some marker for the log, at least this is what [logRequest directive docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/debugging-directives/logRequest.html) say
3. i am not sure that the payload itself is correct: `{name="foo",kind="ConcurrentLeaderboard"}`. the key names should be in quotes as well (but maybe it's just like it's logged, without quotes). and as far as the akka-http can't map payload to `LeaderboardPostRequest` case class, the next option from the route is taken, according to the [compose directive docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/index.html#composing-directives), which is the option with `BadRequest`

Comment: #3 is the problem. I should be using `{"name":"foo","kind":"ConcurrentLeaderboard"}` -- many thanks -- next need to see if there is some way to add diagnostics to the JSON parsing

Comment: Learning how to use Rejections. Strange how the default behavior for this is to do/say nothing, which leads to mysterious failures.